# How to assign list to generic list

Tags: c#, entity-framework

How can I assign return result from table to generic list

This is a WCF service method.

```
public List<T> GetApprovedStateList(DateTime effectiveDate)
    {
        List<T> stateList = null;

        using ( var db = new Context())
        {
            stateList = (from a in db.StateProductList
                         join b in db.States on a.stateID equals b.stateID
                         where a.effectiveDate <= effectiveDate
                         select b).ToList();
        }

        return stateList;
    }
```

Here is my Entity class

```
public class Entities
{
    public class State
    {
        public int stateID { get; set; }
        public string stateCode { get; set; }
        public string stateDescription { get; set; }


    }
```

Here is my context

```
public class Context : DbContext, IDisposable
{
    public Context() : base("EcommConnectionString")
    {
    }
    public List<Entities.State> States { get; set; }
    public List<Entities.Product> Products { get; set; }
    public List<Entities.StateProduct_List> StateProductList { get; set; }


}
```

How can I return a generic list from WCF Service then?

Comment: What would you expect `T` to be here? This isn't a generic method. Even if it were a generic method, how would you expect it to work if `T` wasn't the same type as `StateProductList` returns?

Comment: @JonSkeet I assume the class, rather than the method, is generic.  Of course that leaves the other issues.  (Oh, and it's the states that's returned from the query, not the state product, not that it invalidates your point in any way.)

Comment: @Servy: Maybe. It's hard to tell - I *suspect* the OP is basically a bit confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't, because the list that you haven't isn't the same type as that generic type.  You should be returning a list of the type of the values you actually have.

```
public List<State> GetApprovedStateList(DateTime effectiveDate)
{
    using ( var db = new Context())
    {
        return (from a in db.StateProductList
                     join b in db.States on a.stateID equals b.stateID
                     where a.effectiveDate <= effectiveDate
                     select b).ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: @nimishjain Seeing the entity or your context in no way changes my answer to the question.

Comment: But if I want to return generic list <T> from wcf service method, how could I do it or return List<state> is the correct way?

Comment: @nimishjain You need to return a `List<State>` because you have a list of states.  You don't have a list of some generic type, so you cannot return a list of some generic type.